# How do I add 0 to single digits in this java program?

Tags: java

I am very new to Java. I have barely gotten through the basics (this is my first attempt at using a while loop) and now conveniently have a problem at work that can clearly be solved with programming. We need to add numbers to a print document in the format "xx-xx-xx" such that it will begin with 00-00-00 and end with 99-99-99. Specifically, I need to have leading zeros for the single digits.

I have managed to write a program that prints the numbers we need and I just found out I can output to a text file simply in command prompt (horrifically slow on this old computer using Windows XP and java 1.7), but I can't figure out how to add 0 in front of single digit numbers.

Here's what I have:

```
public class Numbers {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
        while (a<100) {
            if(c<99){
                c = c+1;
                System.out.println(a + "-" + b + "-" + c);
            }
            else if(b<99) {
                c = 0;
                b = b+1;
                System.out.println(a + "-" + b + "-" + c);
            }
            else if(a<99) {
                c = 0;
                b = 0;
                a = a+1;
                System.out.println(a + "-" + b + "-" + c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried a couple of things, but I am most likely not implementing them correctly because, again, I have no idea what I'm doing. I understand that there is a way to format strings in general and there is a printf function and I know there is something you can do with %02d (I've seen String.format("%02d", myNumber) as an answer, but couldn't figure out exactly how to implement that in my code) and I read something about PrintStream and PrintWriter, etc, but I am not nearly experienced enough to know how to use all of that.

The real problem is that I don't exactly have a lot of time to work on this, unfortunately our clients all demand quick turnaround times (they were already asking for a sample yesterday afternoon, hours after we got the job). I'm sure I would eventually be able to figure it out and I will continue trying when I have time, but I also have other work to do and didn't have time last night.

I was thinking of rewriting the code to get rid of the dashes (thinking maybe the fact that there is a string already being printed prevents me from being able to format what I print) but I expect I will run into other problems there.

I would greatly appreciate any input and suggestions for further exploration of java and programming in general (I think I love learning more than just about anything else, I am constantly ravenous and can't be sated).

Comment: `System.out.format("%02d",a);` will print `a` such that it is always two digits in space with a leading 0 in the case `a` is one digit.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear of your troubles. Do you have 3 separate numbers or just one big number?

Comment: This is not critical, but I was originally also hoping to have some way to ask the user to input the initial number (some groups need to start with 03-85-19 for example)

Comment: So to produce 03-85-19 the int would be 38519?

Comment: @FitzwilliamBennet-Darcy this will basically be one big number, with dashes in between, assuming I understood your question correctly.

Comment: @FitzwilliamBennet-Darcy sorry i did misunderstand. the numbers need to be separated by dashes, but that all counts as one number... Each sheet will have a unique set of three numbers, if that is any clearer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do,

```
System.out.printf("%02d-%02d-%02d\n", a, b, c);
```

instead of your println statements.

Comment: Wow, didn't realize it would be that simple. I now understand how the printf works: it's a function that will be in the format (stuff in the quotes) which takes those three arguments that are separated by commas, right?

Answer (score 1):

For a single integral type number `a`, use

`System.out.printf("%02d-%02d-%02d\n",  a / 100 / 100 % 100, a / 100 % 100, a % 100);`

would do it. The `% 100` extracts the last two digits of the `int`s. The `/` is used to extract the bits of the number you need.

If you have three separate numbers `a`, `b`, and `c`, use

`System.out.printf("%02d-%02d-%02d\n", a % 100, b % 100, c % 100);`

Comment: Considering these are three two digit numbers, is the `% 100` and `/ 100` necessary?

Comment: I think Karol has one number. See the question comments especially " user to input the initial number"

Comment: Oh, I see.  I was building off of what they had in the code.  Yeah if they're getting one number and it's all in `a` then you're correct.

Comment: Good dedication to the needs of the asker.

Comment: They do seem rather stressed. Poor thing.

Comment: @FitzwilliamBennet-Darcy Haha, thanks for the concern. I think I just tend to get overexcited, especially when there is an opportunity to learn a lot and there is a deadline. Considering the fact that Codebender's answer worked (tried that first), what does the `% 100` do differently?

Comment: It simply guards against the number being too big for the format so it gives you an extra robustness check. (It extracts the last two digits).

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thank you. Do you have any suggestions as far as channeling the output into a text file? Should I just go on a better computer and still use `java Numbers > numbers.txt` in the command prompt? Does it take long because it's so many lines?

Answer (score 0):

If you want custom outputs:
use the command

```
System.out.printf();
```

in your case you need to use

```
System.out.printf("%02d-%02d-%02d",a,b,c);
```

instead of `System.out.println();` statements